# samb.conf: Where is the "security" parameter?

Tags: linux, windows, file, share, samba

I'm trying to make files in my linux virtual server browsable from my windows. I'm following the instructions given here: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html

However, I cannot find the `security` parameter it's talking about. Can I just create that anywhere under the `[global]`? Or is there a pretty specific place to put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can just specify the "security=" parameter anywhere in the global section.
https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smb.conf.5.html